# Why did the prophet (P.B.U.H) never recite the adhaan?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, history, adhan

As allah loves azaan recitation he love those people who recites azaan but our prophet(P.B.U.H) never recite azaan in his whole life why is it so ?? they do everything which allah likes or allah loves so why not this one ?? why prophet (P.B.U.H) didn't do this ?? is there any reason behind it or this was a fact ??

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Your question seems to already have an answer in the linked duplicate post else consider editing it and showing what you miss. FOr more information on our site and model takje the [tour] and check our [help] .